# How to add a new SSK key to a remote server and make it works? (with Hetzner)

Tags: linux, ssh

### Problem

I've lost an `ssh` key and thus cannot connect anymore into my Hetzner server.
I've read a lot of answers but couldn't make it work...
I've also tried to reset my root password, but even with this I cannot connect to my server..

Below what I've tried (step by step) to fix it, but I'm stucked: I'm not at all a sys admin guru!
Any idea what and where I'm doing it all wrong?
Thanks a lot.

### What I have done:

- **Step 1:** on my Mac, inside my `.ssh` folder: (1) delete all `ssh` keys and (2) delete all contents of `config` and `known_hosts` files.
- **Step 2:** on Hetzner Dashboard, enable `rescue & power cycle` without using `ssh` key

> The rescue system is a network based environment and can be used to
> fix issues preventing a regular boot. It is also useful to install
> custom Linux distributions that are not directly offered by us. You
> are able to mount the servers hard drive inside the rescue system.
> After enabling the rescue system you need to reboot the server in the
> next 60 minutes to activate it. After another reboot your server will
> boot from its local disk again.

- **Step 3:** in my local shell: `ssh root@128.xxx.yy.zzz`.
  The following message appeared and after that I'm connected.

> ```
> The authenticity of host '128.xxx.yy.zzz'' can't be established.
> ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.
> This key is not known by any other names.
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? **yes**
> Warning: Permanently added '128.xxx.yy.zzz' (ED25519) to the list of
> known hosts. root@128.xxx.yy.zzz's password: **ABCYYZ**
> ```

[image: pic1]

- **Step 4:** in my rescue shell: `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`, then `chroot /mnt`. Now, I can `ls`/`cd` and see this.

[image: pic2]

- **Step 5:** in my local shell where I'm inside my `.ssh` folder:

  - `ssh-keygen` (called it `malro` with no passphrase). Now `.ssh` folder looks like this: `config`, `known_hosts`, `known_hosts.old malro` and `malro.pub` (btw `known_hosts` is not empty anymore).
  - `ssh-copy-id -i malro.pub root@128.xxx.yy.zzz`
    and the following message appears.
    So far, so good?

[image]

- **Step 6:** I can now see in my rescue shell if I go to `root@rescue:~/.ssh#` two files (see pic below). I `exit` and `reboot`

[image]

- **Step 7:** In my local shell: `ssh root@128.xxx.yy.zzz` and the following message appears.
  It's where I'm stucked and don't understand...

[image]

Comment: “So far, so good?”—No. You copied the key to the ephemeral rescue system. Also, you now “know” the ephemeral rescue system’s host key.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for having spotted a mistake, but how can I copy the key to my "real" (= not "rescue" system)?